# Why are my plot values incorrect?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

So, I'm currently plotting some data that I have imported to my code via a csv file.

My y values are NO2 columns
My x values are Julian Dates

My data looks as follows:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the Julian date always increases as you would expect. The NO2 data fluctuates upwards and downwards As you would also expect. When I plot it though, this happens:

[image]

I'm wondering how to get my NO2 data to properly distribute?

My code is the following:

```
filein='filein'
fileout='fileout'

import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

headers = ['JulianDate','NO2']

with open(filein, 'r') as sat: ##opens data
    with open(fileout, 'w') as outfile: ##Opens file to write csv data to
        for line in sat:
            if " Julian date" in line:
                writer=csv.writer(outfile)#Specifies to write this to outfile
                writer.writerow(headers)#Writes Headers
                elif "2004" in line: #specifies the year of data I want to look at
                    line=line.split() #Eliminates unnecessary spacing in output
                    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
                    writer.writerow(line)#writes to output file

df=pd.read_csv(output,names=headers,delimiter=',')
plt.scatter(x=df['JulianDate'],y=df['NO2'])
```

Comment: does JulianDate correspond with MJD2000 in your data overview?

Comment: Yes, it does! MJD2000 = Julian Date.

Comment: The data may be strings

Comment: can you zoom in on the axis to see what labelling they have? since the implementatio looks fine, there is a problem with the data itself

Comment: @Cut7er Sadly I'd imagine it is the data too :/ When you zoom in, even where there are obviously points, none show up. I'll try and get to the bottom of why I can "print()" the data and it looks fine but when I plot it something is up.

Comment: Why did you choose a scatter plot for time series data?

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates have to be converted to a datetime format for a neat plot. I would suggest to create a datetime index with converted dates and use the pandas built in plot method.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['JulianDate'].astype('int'), format='%y%j')
df['N02'].plot()
```

N.B. for now I cannot find a proper way to convert the Julian decimal numbers to a datetime format. So with the code above you will lose the information contained in the decimal numbers about the time of the day.